# Inclusion of Lebesgue spaces on finite measure space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in L^{p_{1}}$. We need to show that $f \in L^{p_{2}}$ in a finite measure space.  Where $p_{1} \geq p_{2}$.

My attempt:

$\int |f|^{p_{2}}=\int_{|f|<1} |f|^{p_{2}} + \int_{|f|\geq 1} |f|^{p_{2}}$

$ \leq \mu(X) + \int_{|f|\geq 1} |f|^{p_{1}} < \infty$.

Thus $f \in L^{p_{2}}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for verifying!